# AMD FGLRX driver crashes window manager

Tags: drivers, radeon, lenovo, fglrx, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y470. Every time that I install the FGLRX driver through System Settings -> software Sources -> Additional Drivers, my window manager completely crashes after rebooting, and I receive a blank desktop. I can open a terminal window and load up applications if I want to, but no window manager. If I switch to Gnome, I can also get around.

I have also found that I have the exact same problem if I switch to Linux Mint and try to use Cinnamon, so I know that the problem is not Unity.

Is there some way that I can get these proprietary drivers working?

---

Thanks Naveen, I tried a fresh install, first ran updates and installed linux-headers-generic, and then ran that driver update.

After rebooting, I received an error about xorg not being configured, and it asked me if I wanted to restore the default configuration, which I did.

Now, after reboot I just boot to the Ubuntu graphical login prompt followed by **black screen**. Not sure what to do from here...

Comment: You seem to be using two different accounts, one unregistered. Please see http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/687/117103 on how to get them merged, so you can edit your own post again.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the existing drivers:

> sudo apt-get remove fglrx fglrx-updates

Then install the latest beta driver from [HERE](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-8LINBetaDriver.aspx)